# eclipse won't start after updated from older version

Tags: eclipse

i just updated my eclipse from Ganymede to Luna, but when it restarted, it keeps stocked on the the loading windows with the logo, this my log

```
!SESSION 2014-11-10 10:43:40.720 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-10 10:43:42.303
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid filter directive
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.createOSGiRequirement(ModuleResolutionReport.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printRequirement(ModuleResolutionReport.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.printResolutionEntry(ModuleResolutionReport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReport0(ModuleResolutionReport.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.getResolutionReportMessage(ModuleResolutionReport.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException: Extraneous trailing characters at ")": (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.apache.batik.util.gui)(version=[1.6.0,1.7.0)))
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.FilterImpl$Parser.parse(FilterImpl.java:1420)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.FilterImpl.newInstance(FilterImpl.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.FilterImpl.newInstance(FilterImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleResolutionReport.createOSGiRequirement(ModuleResolutionReport.java:195)
    ... 22 more
```

i tried "eclipse --clean", remove my workspace/.metadata/.plugins, but without luck, what else can i do? , i have a bunch of projects and plugins installed that i don't want to re-install

Comment: Looks like an error in a Batik plugin. Possibly Ganymede accepted the error but Luna does not. It would probably be easiest to install a clean download of Luna.

Comment: Following your advice, i downloaded Luna manually, copied and pasted the files on my current eclipse, and worked, and all the settings,plugins and projects are present :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

I downloaded Luna manually, copied and pasted the files on my current eclipse, and worked, and all the settings,plugins and projects are present :D

i should mentioned that i previously updated all the plugins in eclipse itself using the "Check Updates" option, and after it finished , didn't start anymore,  maybe it worked fine because it was updated previously , probably some files wasn't replaced well when it was updating through eclipse

Comment: Which files exactly did you copy over? Have the same issue as you and also do not want to reinstall. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton i copied all the files inside my current installation into the  downloaded from eclipse